# Virtualbox, nginx suddenly showing default root path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, nginx

I have a development server set up on virtualbox. I'm running Ubuntu 14, nginx, mysql and php-fpm.

I'm having a problem where by it no longer connects. If I enter the IP address it goes to the default nginx page. If I enter the domain I have set up in the hosts, it doesn't connect at all.

The IP in the hosts is correct, as is the domain: `myapp.dev`. It was working fine 30 minutes ago. I haven't made any changes, the only thing I've done is added some code changes to the PHP files in the shared folder.

I have the root folder set to: `/home/user/myapp/public`. This is a shared folder. It is mounted. I have unmounted and remounted, restarted nginx, and I'm still having the same issue.

There's nothing in the error log `/var/log/nginx/error.log'

Any ideas what could be going on here? My config files haven't changed, the root is still set to the shared folder.

**Update**

I've tried to ping both domain and IP and I get the following:

```
ping myapp.dev
PING myapp.dev (192.168.56.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
```

and ...

```
ping 192.168.56.102
PING 192.168.56.102 (192.168.56.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I've restarted the box and the host, to no avail.